# How do I fix this "could not create a custom UI for the shader..." error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, editor, inspector

So I am using the Destroyed Building Kit Demo from the Unity Asset Store and my project is using the Universal Render Pipeline. I moved some objects around then used the undo button a few times and then started getting this error "Could not create a custom UI for the shader 'DBK LWRP/Concrete'. The shader has the following: 'CustomEditor = UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.PBRMasterGUI'. Does the custom editor specified include its namespace? And does the class either derive from ShaderGUI or MaterialEditor?
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)" I get this error every time I click on a gameobject that uses the URP shader provided in the asset package. I am not sure how this happens as I haven't changed anything and I just undo-ed random position changes. How do I fix this? I am not sure what additional information to provide to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unity 2021.3.7 use Shader Graph 12.1.7
This version doesn't have the `class PBRMasterGUI : ShaderGUI`, which was used e.g. in WorldMatURPFree.shader (row 2503):

```
CustomEditor "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.PBRMasterGUI"
```

New version IMHO use the class

```
// Used by the Material Inspector to draw UI for shader graph based materials, when no custom Editor GUI has been specified
class GenericShaderGraphMaterialGUI : ShaderGUI
```

FYI PBRMasterGUI also wasn't a special custom method (you can find its code in Unity 2020) and create your own special custom method (copy & refactoring). I selected to change "my shader" like this:

```
CustomEditor "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.GenericShaderGraphMaterialGUI"
```

After that warning was disappearing